# How do I install IPA on iPhone without iTunes from Windows

Tags: ios, iphone, ipa, phonegap

How would someone install an iPhone app (.IPA) on an iPhone without a Mac or the use of iTunes?  Also, if this wasn't already difficult enough, I don't have access to the iPhone.  I can get the app to the person whom will be testing the app but I have no access to the device it will be installed on or a Mac to distribute the application.

Comment: Read about OTA (Over The Air distribution).

Comment: He would need to qualify as an Enterprise developer, and he can only distribute to employees of his company.  He would still need a Mac.

Answer (score 12):

I know four options for this:

1. Using **iTunes** (Install the utility and copy the app)
2. **iFunbox** (Install the utility and copy the app)
3. **iTools** (Install utility --> Goto Application Tab --> Click on Install --> select application and it will be installed)
4. Online Method: **Diawi** (Upload the IPA and open the URL on device to install IPA)

Comment: upvote for iFunbox, clean and easy, itunes does not support anymore

Comment: iFunbox, easier as hell !! Installs ipa very easily. Super upvote !!

Comment: I'm pretty sure "Install the utility and copy the app" is not a function of iTunes.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is to use a platform like [HockeyApp](https://hockeyapp.net). Create an account (10 apps are free), upload it and tell the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a Mac or iTunes, the best thing you can try is TestFlight.

You send the IPA file to Apple, as you do when you want to publish. But attention: flag the option to manually release the app.

After this, the app isn't released until you do it manually. You can also decide to not publish it anymore and delete it.

Anyway, after you send the app in this way to Apple, you have 90 days to use TestFlight (https://developer.apple.com/testflight/).

TestFlight is a tool giving you the way to install your app on iOS devices without using both a Mac or iTunes. You choose the iOS user and they will receive an email with the step list to install your app (requiriment: install TestFlight on the iOS device).

Answer (score 1):

iFunbox is the easier method
to download.

1. Go to http://www.i-funbox.com and download it.
2. Open IFunBox
3. Connect your IPhone to the computer.
4. When IFunBox detects it, click on the Install button that is located on the upper left corner
5. Choose the file you
   want to have installed. And press Open.
6. Let IFunBox do its
   job, wait for about 0 to 5 mins (depends on file size)

Answer (score 0):

For iPhone,
you must have that device's UDID,
and you have to create provisioning profile and certificate and add that UDID in the certificate and after that you will install the application in that particular device for testing.

Answer (score -1):

Check out Apple's documentation for Ad Hoc builds and delivery.

Comment: Their instructions require the use of a Mac (xCode).

Comment: Without a Mac it is not possible to load an IPA file onto an iPhone that is not jailbroken.  IPA files need a mobile provisioning and to be signed.